# How to change geometry size

Tags: python, scipy, computational-geometry, mesh

I use gmsh in order to create a mesh of complex 3D geometry. From mesh file i can obtain surface elements to create a skin. How can I change coordinates of the skin in oder to make it smaller? Distance between points of the initial and changed surfaces should be the same for every point.
[That's what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCEPu.png)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiply the surface vertices coordinates by a scaling factor.